# PrimeFaces fileUpload component progress bar failing

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Not sure how to proceed debugging this.  I have a misbehaving PrimeFaces fileUpload component.

- I'm working with PrimeFaces 3.5
- fileUpload component progress bar isn't indicating progress during the file upload process
- The file does successfully upload
- Not seeing error messages in my IDE error console
- Nor am I seeing any JavaScript errors in the browser console
- This did work at one time (I inherited this project), tried looking through my git repo to find what changed, but no luck

---

Here's my component code

```
<div class="input input-file">
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{adminFilesController.handleFileUpload}"
        mode="advanced"
        process="@form"
        multiple="true"
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|mp4|avi)$/"
    />
</div>
```

This is the method that it speaks to

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) { 

    try {
        String fileName = event.getFile().getFileName();
        String fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).toLowerCase();
        String randomId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String targetFileName = randomId + "." + fileExtension;
        File targetFile = new File(this.tempPath, targetFileName);
        this.uploadedFiles.put(targetFileName, fileName);

        InputStream inputStream = event.getFile().getInputstream();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[20480];

        try {
            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

            inputStream.close();

            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Can't write file", e.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "An exception occurred trying to process the handleFileUpload Event {0}", e.toString());
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

Any assistance debugging or googling this would be massively appreciated, I'm a little wet behind the ears when it comes to JSF and PrimeFaces.

Comment: What version of Primefaces?

Comment: PrimeFaces v 3.5 @DanielB.Chapman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this one out.  I was including jQueryUI which apparently will bump heads with PrimeFaces.  Simply not including it made the progress bar start working again.  I hope this can help someone!